# Por que no se ejecuta mi funcion con headers en ajax?

Tags: ajax, webservice, post

Tengo problemas al conectar a un webservice, he logrado conectar con php pero noecesito hacerlo con ajax pero no logro avanzar, me he dado cuenta que el token nunca se envia, solo se ejecuta la peticion OPTIONS pero no la POST, algo estoy haciendo mal?, necesito ayuda.

El problema comienza cuando agrego en los headers el bearer token, este es mi código

```
function autologin(respuesta){
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                dataType: "json",
                                data: {data:respuesta.data},
                                headers: {"Authorization":  "Bearer "+respuesta.token},
                                url: "webservices.com",
                            }).done(function (data) {
                                console.log(data);
                            });
                        }
```

Esto me sale en el inspector web:

```
Cabeceras de la respuesta (397 B)
Content-Type    
text/html
Server  
Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By    
ASP.NET
X-Frame-Options 
SAMEORIGIN
Access-Control-Allow-Origin 
*
Access-Control-Allow-Headers    
authorization,content-type
Date    
Fri, 20 Oct 2017 21:37:46 GMT
Connection  
close
Content-Length  
1245



Cabeceras de la petición (474 B)
Host    
host.com
User-Agent  
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel …) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0
Accept  
text/html,application/xhtml+xm…plication/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language 
es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate, br
Access-Control-Request-Method   
POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers  
authorization
Origin  
https://midominio.com
Connection  
keep-alive
```

Comment: ¿Cómo pruebas las peticiones?, no se si estás familiarizado con [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).

Comment: Lo estoy haciendo directamente en mi web ya que una de los requisitos es que la peticion salga de dominio seguro, he probado con postman por esto mismo me sale error

Comment: ¿Qué retorna Postman? dices que lo has logrado con PHP, tal vez te falte enviar algún datos en el header...

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error, supongo que porque es necesario que la peticion salga de una direccion segura.